# Importing JS files outside Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

So, i have a script that creates a global object

```
(function() {

   window.GlobalThing = {}

})();
```

This script will also fill this object attributes

```
   if (!GlobalThing .Resource) { GlobalThing .Resource = require('./Resource'); }
```

Then, some other scripts that are not bundled with webpack need to use this GlobalThing. I`ve tryed to make it global using ProvidePlugin for example:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        'GlobalThing': path.join(__dirname,"Path/GlobalThing.js")
    })
],
```

I've tryed adding an Alias as well

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
       'GlobalThing': path.join(__dirname,"Path/GlobalThing.js")
    }
}
```

I have tryed doing something like this in the end of my GlobalThing.js file as well:

```
(function(){
   window.GlobalThing = GlobalThing;
})();
```

Then i had to import to run the script, so i got a random js file inside the webpack to test it:

```
import GlobalThing from "GlobalThing ";
```

Still, it seems some scripts cannot `see`the GlobalThing. If i bundle everything up with webpack, it works, but i didnt want to as our app is very old and have some very old stuff. Is there a way i can expose GlobalThing to those older scripts ?

Comment: *"it seems some scripts cannot seethe GlobalThing"* Your webpack bundle must be loaded before the older scripts are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

`ProvidePlugin` takes a module name (i.e. string) and internally uses `require` to load it. So that wont help you in loading your own script.

That said, following should work:

- Keep the `GlobalThing` script out of webpack bundling
- Make sure the script itself is copied to the output folder
- Make sure the `index.html` (or whatever html page you are using) has the scripts in the order `GlobalThingScript.js` **followed** by webpack `bundle.js`

To give you more insight:
When webpack bundles the scripts other than `GlobalThingScript.js`, it doesnt even know there is something called `GlobalThing`. It just bundles the other files.

That would mean it is upto you to make sure the `GlobalThingScript.js` is also made it to the final `output` folder. Also, the html source should use `<script>` tags to include the `GlobalThingScript.js` **before** webpack `bundle.js`.

In case problem persists, please do edit the OP to include the html source.

Hope that helps.